# Google exact search when a search phrase contains minus (-)

Tags: google-search

The Google search engine explains that

> When you put a word or phrase in quotes, the results will only include pages with the same words in the same order as what's inside the quotes.
>   Note: Only use this if you're looking for an exact word or phrase, otherwise you'll exclude many helpful results by mistake.
>   Example: "imagine all the people"

I want to find exact phrase containing "-include" meaning a usage of g++ compiler. It's strange, but all search engines ignore my minus sign despite I put the phrase in double quotes in my query `"g++" "-include" option`

Why? How to find what I actually want?

Comment: Also: [How can I search Google for a negative number?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50092/354)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this with Google, and I did some more research and there doesn't seem to be a way.

I did however find [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50113) that links to a search site called [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) which will take your input literally, as-is.