# Google search for "-1" returning no results

Tags: google-search

How come that searching for "-1" on Google Search Engine returns:

*Your search - -1 - did not match any documents.
Suggestions:
Make sure that all words are spelled correctly. Try different keywords. Try more general keywords.*

Aren't there really results for -1?

Comment: For me -1 returns something.

Comment: Google tends to ignore negative numbers. Searching any number, with or without a minus sign will return approximately the same results. [try it with error codes, for example].

Comment: Note this is also a special case of searching for special characters in google so you might find this answer useful: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search

Comment: There is a puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97362/google-cannot-find-me related to this. Not exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I search Google for a negative number?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50092/how-can-i-search-google-for-a-negative-number)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `-` is used to exclude something from a search. This is usually negated if you quote everything, so technically `"-1"` should work.

That said, Google tends to ignore negative numbers, so the best alternative is to write out the minus.

If you search for `minus 1` or `negative 1` Google will actually give results that include `-1`.

Answer (score 14):

For such things I usually go to [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com), where you can search for things including, well, symbols, such as & @var x++ etc.

Comment: As a demo I tried searching for `-1` on `en.wikipedia.org`, but it didn't really work. After some digging, it turns out Wikpedia uses the proper minus sign, `−` Unicode U+2212, instead of the hyphen-minus U+2d. So I tried `−1`, but it didn't find the page [−1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%921), which is strange. Meanwhile, doing the equivalent search on Google works.

Answer (score 5):

Google search uses the `-` symbol to exclude results.

You can fix this by escaping the `-`, e.g. `\-`. This makes Google process the raw symbol. However, Google often ignores the negative sign even if you do this.

To get the desired results, write out the sign, i.e. `negative 1`.